# How to get rid of 0.000 and change 5.*10^n to 3*10^n on Log Plots?

Tags: bugs, code-request, broken-code, version-13.3

Using Version 13.1.0.0 (**Edit:** MacOS BigSur Version 11.6, Hardware M1 chip)

In order to show some Log (or LogLog) plot features that I find annoying, here is some code:

```
A=3/2;B=1/1000;G=1;
{Slider[Dynamic[G],{1/10,8}],"G"->Dynamic[G],"\n",Slider[Dynamic[A],{1/2,2}],"A"->Dynamic[A],"\n",Slider[Dynamic[B],{1/10000,1/100}],"B"->Dynamic[B],"\n",Dynamic[LogLogPlot[
Evaluate[ B/(G Gamma[G+1] Zeta[1+G](2-2^-G)) {Log[1+A/(-1+E^(B t))]^G,A^G E^(-B G t)}],{t,0,3000},PlotRange->{{0.01,Full},{0,Full}},WorkingPrecision->20,ImageSize->Medium]]}
```

Please notice that the code this generates shows 0.000 rather than 0.001 on the y-axis and show numerical values at 5.x 10$^n$ rather than 3 x 10$^n$, where both the decimal points are unneeded and the divisions at 5 times ten to a power results in collisions a lot sooner than at 3 times ten to a power because `N[Log10[3]]` is 0.477121 or very close to 0.5 on a `Log10` plot, whereas `N[Log10[5]]` is 0.69897, and not close to 0.5.

Are there any fixes for these annoying features that do not involve yards of Tick coding?

[image]

Notice the positions of the numbers
`NumberLinePlot[{Log10[1], Log10[3], Log10[5], Log10[10]}]`

[image]

Re: Yards of tick code. For example,

```
FrameTicks -> {{{3, 3, {0, .01}}, {4, "", {0, .01}}, {5, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {6, "", {0, .01}}, {7, "", {0, .01}}, {8, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {9, "", {0, .01}}, {10, 10, {0, .015}}, {20, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {30, 30, {0, .01}}, {40, "", {0, .01}}, {50, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {60, "", {0, .01}}, {70, "", {0, .01}}, {80, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {90, "", {0, .01}}, {100, 100, {0, .015}}, {200, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {300, 300, {0, .01}}, {400, "", {0, .01}}, {500, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {600, "", {0, .01}}, {700, "", {0, .01}}, {800, 
    "", {0, .01}}, {900, "", {0, .01}}, {1000, 
    1000, {0, .015}}, {2000, "", {0, .01}}, {3000, 
    3000, {0, .01}}, {4000, "", {0, .01}}, {5000, "", {0, .01}}}, 
  Automatic}
```

To format an x-axis like the following:

[image]

PS, I put this in as `bugs` even though this has not been vetted because I do not need to have someone verify that $0.000\neq0.001$, i.e., seeing is believing.

**Edit** On 2023-08-02 I received notification from Wolfram that Mathematica 13.3.1.0 has fixed the M1 chip code bug. Indeed, the same code as above now displays 0.001 rather than 0.000 on the $y$-axis.
[image]

Comment: I'm running 13.1.0.0 on a mac, and I see `0.001` where your picture shows `0.000`.

Comment: 13.1.0.0 on Windows 10 also produces `0.001` rather than `0.000`.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: @lericr I am using MacOS BigSur Version 11.6, Hardware M1 chip.

Comment: @JimB So I tried MacBook Pro, macOS 11.5.2 Mathematica 12.3.0.0 and it shows `0.001` for the same code that on my iMac computer as produces `0.000`. So no, I can't explain why that is.

Comment: So, the first issue seems to be M1 specific. If I understand, there are two other issues (which, by the way, might warrant breaking up this question to separate the bug): (1) the format of the tick labels, specifically the superfluous decimal point, and (2) the choice of which ticks to label. I believe you can address both of these with the Ticks option. FindDivisions is a helpful function. Creating your own helper function for formatting the tick labels is usually easy. But I don't know what you consider "yards of Tick coding".

Comment: @lericr I put in some "yards" as an example. Now sure, once on has figured out how to encode the ticks, one can then make an table of `If` statements to do that, however, the whole process is really slow and inefficient and takes a degree of compulsive obsession to encode that I find too demanding. Regarding breaking up the question, I considered that to begin with. However, please consider that I am just showing features on a single graph that are irksome, and if it were just one issue, I might not even ask.

Comment: Well, first off, you don't need to specify the ticks you don't want (i.e. the ones where you use "" as the label). So, this works just as well: `FrameTicksSpec = {{{3, 3, {0, .01}}, {10, 10, {0, .015}}, {30, 30, {0, .01}}, {100, 100, {0, .015}}, {300, 300, {0, .01}}, {1000, 1000, {0, .015}}, {3000, 3000, {0, .01}}}, Automatic}`

Comment: @lericr I cannot find FrameTicksSpec in the documentation. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I set this variable and then used it in a plot: `FrameTicks -> FrameTicksSpec`.

Comment: @lericr Humm, OK, but where exactly do I specify `FrameTicks -> FrameTicksSpec` and how do I do that? Needed Frame to put in the {x,y)-axes labels in their usual positions for published graphs.

Comment: Exactly as I showed in my answer. Although if you're going to use FrameTicks instead of Ticks, you'll probably have to change the structure (Ticks just expects x&y, but FrameTicks expects something for all four edges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the update, and applying some simplification so we can focus on the ticks, here is an approach that computes the option for the ticks.

```
TickSpec = 
  {Join[
     Table[{3*10^i, StringForm["3e``", i], .01}, {i, 0, Floor[Log10[3000]]}], 
     Table[{1*10^(i + 1), StringForm["1e``", i + 1], .02}, {i, 0, Floor[Log10[3000]]}]], {}};
LogLogPlot[Log10[x], {x, 0, 3000}, Ticks -> TickSpec]
```

You could parameterize this to get rid of the hard-coded 3000.

I should add that I didn't see in your examples why using FrameTicks was necessary, so I just used Ticks. But a similar treatment could be used for FrameTicks, although the format is slightly different.

Comment: I approved it. Yeah, I wasn't really careful to get the exact ticks you wanted. I was focusing on how to specify the structure of the option. And if you really did want some unlabeled ticks, that could be worked in as well. As long as you have a well-specified rule for which ticks should appear and how to label them, you should be able to avoid "yards of tick coding".

Comment: I should be able to take it from here, thanks.

Comment: However, the bug is still a bug.

Comment: Agreed. Did you report it?

Comment: No. I can, just not today.